# iphone what to use as there are no "radio buttons"

Tags: iphone, radio-button, uiswitch

For the iPhone, I havent been able to find anything like a radio button that triggers the other buttons in a group. So what would everyone suggest using?  UISwitch I guess and do something to trigger the others in the group when an other is selected?

If I had several UISwitch objects how would I trigger the others to be the opposite of what I switched?

Comment: Apps like the Settings app use a table view to represent a radio button group. I made a custom table view controller that mimics what the Settings app does (including logic for deselecting other cells when I select one) but haven't gotten around to releasing its source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also used a custom UISegmentedControl. Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* buttons;

- (void)touchDownAction:(UIButton*)button {
    [self dimAllButtonsExcept:button];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(touchDownAtSegmentIndex:)])
        [delegate touchDownAtSegmentIndex:[buttons indexOfObject:button]];
}

-(void) dimAllButtonsExcept:(UIButton*)selectedButton {
    for (UIButton* button in buttons) {
        if (button == selectedButton) {
            button.selected = YES;
            button.highlighted = YES;
        } else {
            button.selected = NO;
            button.highlighted = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

The full code is at https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/tree/master/sources/main/ui/custom/segControl

Comment: I wonder if a person every knows everything about a programming language and development environment?! Just about the time I think I found everything something new comes up again...  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

I use buttons with images that act like radio buttons. i.e. an off image and an on image. The nice thing about this approach is it is very simple to implement and you can use the image to control the state of the button control. It works as a simple toggle and no fancy button state is needed. You can easily add code to the method that does something when buttons are on or off, in the example I just call a method which is writing some user defaults.

It should be quite easy to adapt to create radio button functionality.

```
 -(IBAction)tickboxControl:(id)sender{  
      NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);  
      bgImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tickedBox.png"];  
      bgImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tickBoxEmpty.png"];  
      UIButton *buttonClicked = (UIButton *)sender;  
   UIImage *imageOfClicked = [buttonClicked imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];  
      if (imageOfClicked == bgImageOff) {  
           [self setButtonFlags: [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender tag]] : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];  
           [buttonClicked setImage:bgImageOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
      } else{  
           [self setButtonFlags: [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender tag]] : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] ];  
           [buttonClicked setImage:bgImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
      }       
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I am still trying to grasp all of this.  While I can see how this works, I really dont know how to plug it into my code.  Can I use this with IB?  Wonder why iPhone SDK doesnt have a radio button anyway?!

Answer (score 4):

I created a project that shows exactly how to achieve what you are asking to do. 
You can change the graphics from checkboxes (which I find a little better to see and understand on a device) to radio buttons.

Read the debug log to understand the logic.

If you have any questions give me a shout.

[Radio Buttons Example Project (XCode4)](http://www.handstream.co.uk/RadioButtonExample.zip)

[this is in reply to your comments below]

Answer (score 2):

I’ve used a UISegmentedControl as radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for a radio button in iOS:

```
@interface RadioButtonViewController : UIViewController

{
    //for radio button
    IBOutlet UIButton *radioButton1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *radioButton2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *selectedValue;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
   }

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *radioButton1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *radioButton2;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *selectedValue;
-(IBAction)userChangedButtonClicked:(id)sender
@end
```

Write code in .m file and specify the default and selected image in storyboard inspector window and give the tag value each button.

**RadioButtonViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)userChangedButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *senderBtn = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (senderBtn.tag == 101 && !self.radioButton1.selected)
    {
       self.radioButton1.selected = TRUE;
        self.radioButton2.selected = FALSE;
      selectedValue.text = label1.text;
    }else if (senderBtn.tag == 102 && !self.radioButton2.selected)
    {
        self.radioButton1.selected = FALSE;
        self.radioButton2.selected = TRUE;
       selectedValue.text = label2.text;
    }
}
```