# options control in ios (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to show options to choose in my View. I did not found a control for that. Any suggestion howto do that ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone what to use as there are no "radio buttons"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091023/iphone-what-to-use-as-there-are-no-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use 3 different buttons for the check box,now set different tag for the buttons and set default and selected image for the button.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I see , we have to do this from scratch with basic uibutton objects.